# How can I find duplicate classes amongst dependencies with SBT

Tags: sbt

I'm migrating a project from Apache Maven to sbt.

My project has lots of dependencies (over 200), and sometimes, a class can be duplicated that can lead to strange effects.

In Maven I've been using [maven-duplicate-finder-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin) for detecting such cases.

The only solution I can see is to generate a big jar with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, and configure to complain about duplicated classes.  I haven't tried it yet.

How can I do it with SBT?

References:

- List of [SBT plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Community-Plugins.html)
- SBT assembly plugin [documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly).

Comment: You'd be better off asking the question on [the sbt mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sbt-dev) as it doesn't really belong here.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I don't know why this was marked off-topic.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Never mind. The question has been edited to fit the Stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a plugin which finds duplicate classes, but there is [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) which will list out all dependencies including transitive ones. This way you can analyze version conflicts and such. Hopefully this will help with your use case.

Comment: Your solution is good.  The problem is that the same artifact, can be repeated in Maven repositories with differents `groupId`/`artifactId`, and even some `jar`s embed 3rd party ones, creating a repetition of .class, that can belong to different versions, and a clash will occur.