# How to discover the library that defines a class from sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, classpath

For example, I would like to discover what library from the defined classpath declares a class like ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP ?

Any decent IDE offers a feature where you can search for such types(find type in Eclipse), but how can this be done in SBT? There is any task/command/plugin that can help me with this?

Such a feature would be also useful for class collisions detection (if multiple jars would define the same class): see this related question [How can I find duplicate classes amongst dependencies with SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635346/how-can-i-find-duplicate-classes-amongst-dependencies-with-sbt) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique I thought I knew actually didn't work well.

### Going through Analysis (doesn't work)

```
core> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...

scala> val a = (compile in Compile).eval
a: sbt.inc.Analysis = Analysis: 69 Scala sources, 1092 classes, 2 external source dependencies, 4 binary dependencies

scala> val stamps = a.stamps
stamps: sbt.inc.Stamps = Stamps for: 1092 products, 69 sources, 4 binaries, 4 classNames

scala> val classNames = stamps.classNames
classNames: Map[java.io.File,String] = Map(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar -> java.lang.Object, /Users/eugene/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.6.jar -> scala.Function1, /Users/eugene/.ivy2/cache/org.typelevel/machinist_2.11/jars/machinist_2.11-0.3.0.jar -> machinist.Ops, /Users/eugene/.ivy2/local/org.spire-math/algebra_2.11/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/algebra_2.11.jar -> algebra.Eq)
```

At first glance this looks useful, but the direction of Map is from `File` to `String`, so it's actually not very useful.

### Java reflection

If you can get hold of `Class`, you could do something like this:

```
scala> a.getClass.getClassLoader match { case ucl: java.net.URLClassLoader => ucl.getResource(a.getClass.getName.replace('.', '/') + ".class")  }
res13: java.net.URL = jar:file:/Users/eugene/.conscript/boot/scala-2.10.5/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.9-RC1/incremental-compiler-0.13.9-RC1.jar!/sbt/inc/MAnalysis.class
```